# How do I make spicy mayonnaise like Japanese restaurants use for sushi?

Tags: japanese-cuisine, sushi, mayonnaise

I've tried mixing mayonnaise and hot sauce together and it didn't taste right at all. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Japanese spicy mayo is made with [Kewpie mayo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000W5JAXQ) and [Shichimi tōgarashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shichimi). You really just mix them to taste.

Comment: How is Kewpie different than regular mayo?

Comment: The difference between Kewpi styled mayo and western is mainly whether egg whites are included. Check out the following: [making japanese style mayo](https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/japanese-kewpie-style-mayo)

Answer (score 10):

You can also use regular mayo and [sriricha](http://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=siricha&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sriracha+sauce) hot sauce.  Ain't authentic, but it's a lot easier to come by, for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

Kewpie mayo and Shichimi. Sriracha has vinegar so it tastes different.

Answer (score 1):

Japanese spicy mayo is "Kewpie" mixed with Sriracha.   Kewpie and sriracha can be found at your local asian market...

Answer (score 0):

Not 'authentic', but I make it with mayo, chili oil, chili powder, crushed garlic, and honey. It's good on vegetables, too, especially cauliflower for some reason.

Answer (score -3):

How about blending the mayo with wasabi powder? It will be different than the hot pepper heat but you'll taste it!

Answer (score -3):

It's  sriracha hot sauce  mayo and sesame oil. That's it.